# TypeError : 'str' does not support the buffer interface

Tags: python, string

I'm developing a graphical interface with python 3, so I found some code that helps me to send a file (gcode) to GRBL, but this code is in python 2. I tried to modify the program to work on python 3.

```
import serial
import time

# Open grbl serial port
s = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyS0',115200)

# Open g-code file
f = open(r'/home/pi/Downloads/spinner.gcode')

# Wake up grbl
s.write("\r\n\r\n".encode("utf8"))
time.sleep(2)   # Wait for grbl to initialize
s.flushInput()  # Flush startup text in serial input

# Stream g-code to grbl
for line in f:
    l = line.strip() # Strip all EOL characters for streaming
    print ('Sending: ' + l)
    s.write(l + '\n') # Send g-code block to grbl
    grbl_out = s.readline() # Wait for grbl response with carriage return
    print( ' : ' + grbl_out.strip())

# Wait here until grbl is finished to close serial port and file.
raw_input("  Press <Enter> to exit and disable grbl.")

# Close file and serial port
f.close()
s.close()
```

When I run it, it shows me an error:

> TypeError : 'str' does not support the buffer interface

Comment: Please add a full stack trace

Comment: `s.write("\r\n\r\n").encode("utf8")` doesn't look right...

Comment: Yes the correct syntax is : s.write("\r\n\r\n".encode("utf8")), but  it shows me the same problem :(

Comment: This question lacks a [mcve] or even a traceback. The code that caused the error might be in the `serial` module that you import.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just guessing since you didn't show the stack trace, or even the line that generates the error. But I think it can be fixed:

```
s.write((l + '\n').encode("utf8"))
```

Comment: it doesn't work :( , TypeError : Can't convert 'bytes' object to str implicitly

Comment: @SkaouzMacac You really need to report (and pay attention to, yourself) *which* line is generating your errors.  In the case of "Can't convert 'bytes' object to str implicitly" it's probably the `+` operation two lines below. You can avoid it by saying `grbl_out = s.readline().decode('utf8')`

Comment: @jez thank you , but the problem now is : AttributeError 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'strip'

Comment: @SkaouzMacac unless you put the *full error trace* into the question, we're just flying blind here.